# textAlignent to right in cellForRowAt in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, text-alignment

I cannot manage to get my text to align to the right side of my table view. My code sets the text alignment to right but it only justifies the text if there is more that 1 line. Here is my cellforRowAt code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    return cell
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the subtitle UITableViewCell style aren't you? This is a style that for what ever reason don't allow you to override the text label's alignment.

To solve this problem, you can make a simple subclass of UITableViewCell with a label in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Let change the style of cell to `default`:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

I created a subtitle cell in the storyboard and I realized the `textLabel`'s size is fit to its content. So you can't align the text of `textLabel`. But you can do this with basic cell, its size is matched to the cell.

[image]